# simplecursoradapter treat field as integer resource value

Tags: android, string, integer, simplecursoradapter

I have some data in a table on my database. On a column I have integer values that refer to a string resource.

I want that when I load the values with my adapter my ListView display the String related to the value, but not the integer value itself.

```
    String[] nfrom = {ProfileManager.EVENT_NAME,ProfileManager.NAME,ProfileManager.PRIORITY};
    int[] nto = {R.id.eventType,R.id.profileToSwitch,R.id.priority};

    triggersCursor = profileManager.getAllModTriggerCursors();
    startManagingCursor(triggersCursor);
    triggersAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.trigger_item_layout,triggersCursor,nfrom,nto);
    lst_triggers.setAdapter(triggersAdapter);
```

The ListView display '2131034132', not the String.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to [customize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) the binding process for this field.  For Example:

```
setViewValue(...){
   boolean isCustomBinding = false;

   if(view.getId() == R.id.my_id){
       TextView tv = (TextView) view;
       tv.setText(cursor.getInt(columnIndex));
       isCustomBinding = true;
   }

   return isCustomBinding; // returning false will allow the automatic binder to work.
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if they are correct or useful.